# GraphQL Spring Boot Query returns null in playground and in postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I have very simple Spring Boot GraphQL project that uses dependencies: graphql-spring-boot-starter-test, graphql-spring-boot-starter, graphql-java-tools, playground-spring-boot-starter all in version 12. I have simple query:

```
type Query {
   getItemById(id: ID) : Item
}
type Item {
   id: ID!
   name: String
}
```

And in Java:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Item {
   private String id;
   private String name;
}

@Component
@Log
public class ItemResolver implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;

    public Item getItemById(String id) {
        log.info("query called with " + id);
        return Item .builder().id("testId").name("first").build();
        //return webClient.get().uri("/item/find?id="+id).retrieve().bodyToMono(Item.class)
        //        .block();
    }
}
```

If i call this query in either in playground or in postman i get null in responce.
Query:

```
{
   getItemById(id: "testId") {
       id, name
   }
}
```

Response:

```
{
   "data": {
       "getItemById":null
   }
}
```

Whats makes this even weirder to me, is that response is correct when called from test:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class UserResolverTestIT {

    @Autowired
    private GraphQLTestTemplate graphQLTestTemplate;

    @Test
    void testGetAllTacos() throws IOException {

        String rq = getQuery();
        String rs = getResponse();
        GraphQLResponse graphQLResponse = graphQLTestTemplate.postForResource("query.graphqls");
        
        Assertions.assertThat(graphQLResponse.getRawResponse().getBody())
                .isEqualToIgnoringNewLines(rs);
    }
    
    private String getResponse() {
        return "{\"data\":{\"getItemById\":{\"id\":\"testId\",\"name\":\"first\"}}}";
    }
}
```

and query.json

```
{
  "query":"getItemById(id: \"testId\") {    id    firstName  }}"
}
```

So why its not working in playground or postman? I dont see any errors in logs, and also resolver method does not get logged, like its never called
Graphql schema files are inside resources directory, and in application.properties there is defined property: graphql.tools.schema-location-pattern=*.graphqls

Comment: can you add the graphql provider class